# In which master page do I link my custom CSS link in sharepoint 2019 site?

Tags: custom-masterpage, 2019, cssregistration, style.css

I have 4 different master pages, seattle.master, oslo.master, v4.master and minimal.master. From my research on google, I found that the corev15.css lies in seattle.master and tried overriding that by inline-style but that din't work for me. I tried the same thing in all 4 master pages but failed. It's not working at all. I also tried writing a custom CSS Override.css and linking to those pages but failed. None of these worked. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="_catalogs/masterpage/Override.css" After="corev15.css" runat="server" />
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="https://one.echristus.net/sites/test-TFS/Style%20Library/Override.css" runat="server"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://one.echristus.net/sites/test-TFS/Style%20Library/Override.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_catalogs/masterpage/Override.css" />
```

This is my inline styling.

```
<style type="text/css">
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
.o365cs-nav-header16 .o365cs-nav-centerAlign{
    display: none!important;
}

.o365cs-base .ms-Icon--Waffle::before {
    display: none!important;
}

.o365cs-base .ms-Icon--Settings::before{ 
    display: none!important;
}

.o365cs-base .ms-Icon--Help::before {
    display: none!important;
}

.o365cs-base * {
    display: none!important;        
}

.o365cs-nav-header16 .o365cs-nav-o365Branding {
    display: none!important;
}
```

}

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    #SuiteNavPlaceHolder {
    display: none!important;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Maybe they're not working because the styles you are trying to override are in SharePoint Online only, and not in SharePoint 2013? I just opened a site in my on-prem 2013 farm, and opened a page in a SP Online site, and searched for some of those classes you reference, and I only found them in the page from SP Online.

Comment: @DylanCristy Sorry for the confusion. It's SP 2019 teams site. Is there any way I can over write the styling. Your time and effort is much appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: I think you should be able to override the styling, yes.  If those classes exist in 2019 and the way you have your selectors set up accurately target things, I'm not sure why it wouldn't be working. Have you checked the Network section of browser dev tools to make sure your CSS file is getting pulled in and loaded?

Comment: Yes, I have checked and neither the CSS file nor inline styling loads at all so, I am quite confused where I need to write or link my CSS styling. I mean in which page or section do I need to do that ? All this way, I have been seeing the above mentioned CssRegistration or <link> either have worked everybody. Not sure if M the only one facing this situation. Thanks again